# Opensource username-password storage software which works on an internal server and is multi-user

Tags: security, password-protection

I am trying to find something for my company to store internal usernames and passwords within the company server where we can have different users for different departments. Is there any such software I can try? I can create a database using mongodb or postgres but I just need a password software to upload my database in and then host it on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LastPass for this, they have premium and enterprise plans which may do what you need: https://lastpass.com/

Comment: Can it be multi-computer?

Comment: Yes. It is used a my work. It allows you to share login information with groups of employees, allows employees to create logins at websites and store the login details in the companys account (so that the login details don't get lost when the emplyee leaves or is sick), etc. quite handy